# ANDROID - Test wifi connection

Tags: android, wifi

I want to test an wifi connection in Android. My procedure always return CONNECTED, no matter what password i use or whet type is network. 
What's wrong in code below.

```
String checkConnection(ScanResult sr,String password) 
{
        String sreturn="NOT CONNECTED";

        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", sr.SSID);
        wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", password);

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

        if (wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig) != -1) 
        {
                if (wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true)) {
                    sreturn = "CONNECTED";
                    wifiManager.disableNetwork(netId);        
                }
                wifiManager.removeNetwork(netId);
        }
        return sreturn;
    }
```

*

Comment: Could you elaborate your post and tell us what the expected result is, what the observed result is and what you have tried to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

String checkConnection(ScanResult sr,String password) 
{
        String sreturn="NOT CONNECTED";

```
    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", sr.SSID);
    wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", password);

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

    int netId=wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);        

    if (netId != -1) 
    {
            if (wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true)) {
                sreturn = "CONNECTED";
                wifiManager.disableNetwork(netId);        
            }
            wifiManager.removeNetwork(netId);
    }
    return sreturn;
}
```